# Two questions about mapnik

Tags: mapnik, xml

I newbie have two newbie questions about Mapnik.

1. Does Mapnik allow generation tiles with float zoom level?
2. I have osm file for my region. I want generate images. Where i can download full xml file for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Mapnik allow generation tiles with float zoom level?

Mapnik is a *renderer*, not a server or tile generator. A generator like TileMill cannot generate tiles with float zoom levels because there's no spec. You might be able to get generate_tiles.py to.

> I have osm file for my region. I want generate images. Where i can download full xml file for it?

You'll need to import the `.osm` file into a PostGIS database, but if you can get there, look into [this page on the stylesheet and Mapnik in context of OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik#Rendering_with_Mapnik).